# Error: File ended while scanning use of \kvsetkeys

Tags: errors

I´m pretty new to LaTeX. When generating the pdf, I receive the error:

> File ended while scanning use of \kvsetkeys

I´m using the standard code developed by an brazilian university to write my phd dissertation.

Could anyone help me?

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[
12pt,
openright,          
oneside,            
a4paper,             
english,            
french,             
spanish,            
brazil              
]{abntex2}

\usepackage{lmodern}                        
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage{lastpage}           
\usepackage{indentfirst}        .
\usepackage{color}              
\usepackage{graphicx}           
\usepackage{microtype}          
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}
\usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{backref}    
\usepackage[alf,abnt-etal-list=0,abnt-etal-cite=2,abnt-etal-text=it,abnt-repeated-author-omit=yes]{abntex2cite} 
\renewcommand{\backrefpagesname}{Citado na(s) página(s):~}
\renewcommand{\backref}{}
\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{
    \ifcase #1 %
        Nenhuma citação no texto.%
    \or
        Citado na página #2.%
    \else
        Citado #1 vezes nas páginas #2.%
    \fi}%

\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}
\makeatletter
\hypersetup{
%pagebackref=true,
pdftitle={\@title}, 
pdfauthor={\@author},
pdfsubject={\imprimirpreambulo},
pdfcreator={LaTeX with abnTeX2},
pdfkeywords={abnt}{latex}{abntex}{abntex2}{trabalho acadêmico}, 
colorlinks=true,            
linkcolor=black,            
citecolor=black,            
filecolor=magenta,          
urlcolor=black,
%bookmarksdepth=4}
\makeatother
\setlength{\parindent}{1.3cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.2cm}  % tente também \onelineskip
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{brazil}
\frenchspacing 
\imprimircapa
\imprimirfolhaderosto
\setlength{\absparsep}{18pt} 
\begin{resumo}  
\vspace{\onelineskip}
\end{resumo}
\begin{resumo}[Abstract]
\vspace{\onelineskip} 
\noindent 
\end{resumo}
\pdfbookmark[0]{\listfigurename}{lof}
\listoffigures*
\cleardoublepage
\pdfbookmark[0]{\listtablename}{lot}
\listoftables*
\cleardoublepage
\begin{siglas}
\end{siglas}
\pdfbookmark[0]{\contentsname}{toc}
\tableofcontents*
\cleardoublepage
\textual
\chapter{Introdução}
\section{Apresentação}
\phantompart
\postextual
\bibliography{Bibliografia}
\begin{apendicesenv}
\end{apendicesenv}
\begin{anexosenv}
\end{anexosenv}
\phantompart
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: You would get that if you had `\kvsetkeys{`  with no closing brace anywhere. If you show no code that is about the only thing anyone could guess.

Comment: Thanks, David. I just posted the code. I´m using the standard code developed by an brazilian university to write my phd dissertation.

Comment: I get the error `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.`

Comment: if I correct that (stray `.` on line 17) then I get the error `! LaTeX Error: File `pgf-pie.sty' not found.`

Comment: You have `%bookmarsdepth=4}` and the `%` hides the closing `}`. Put the brace on the following line, if you want to keep the commented entry.

Comment: In my case using brackets, i..e `()`, inside one of the `\hypersetup` commands caused this error.

Answer (score 2):

Your main error here is the commented closing bracket in command `\hypersetup`.  Change it to (see the marking `<=======`:

```
\hypersetup{%
% pagebackref=true,
  pdftitle={\@title}, 
  pdfauthor={\@author},
  pdfsubject={\imprimirpreambulo},
  pdfcreator={LaTeX with abnTeX2},
  pdfkeywords={abnt}{latex}{abntex}{abntex2}{trabalho acadêmico}, 
  colorlinks=true,            
  linkcolor=black,            
  citecolor=black,            
  filecolor=magenta,          
  urlcolor=black,
%bookmarksdepth=4 % <===================================================
} % <===================================================================
```

After commenting a few other options and adding some missing commands your code compiles. See the following MWE (and please check the lines marked with `<====`):

```
\documentclass[%
12pt,
openright,          
oneside,            
a4paper,             
%english,            
%french,             
%spanish,            
brazil              
]{abntex2}

\usepackage{lmodern}                        
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage{lastpage}           
\usepackage{indentfirst}        %.<=====================================
\usepackage{color}              
\usepackage{graphicx}           
\usepackage{microtype}          
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}
\usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{backref}    
\usepackage[alf,abnt-etal-list=0,abnt-etal-cite=2,abnt-etal-text=it,abnt-repeated-author-omit=yes]{abntex2cite} 
\renewcommand{\backrefpagesname}{Citado na(s) página(s):~}
\renewcommand{\backref}{}
\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{
    \ifcase #1 %
        Nenhuma citação no texto.%
    \or
        Citado na página #2.%
    \else
        Citado #1 vezes nas páginas #2.%
    \fi}%

\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}
\makeatletter
\hypersetup{%
% pagebackref=true,
  pdftitle={\@title}, 
  pdfauthor={\@author},
  pdfsubject={\imprimirpreambulo},
  pdfcreator={LaTeX with abnTeX2},
  pdfkeywords={abnt}{latex}{abntex}{abntex2}{trabalho acadêmico}, 
  colorlinks=true,            
  linkcolor=black,            
  citecolor=black,            
  filecolor=magenta,          
  urlcolor=black,
%bookmarksdepth=4 % <===================================================
} % <===================================================================
\makeatother
\setlength{\parindent}{1.3cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.2cm}  % tente também \onelineskip
\makeindex

\author{John Doe} % <===================================================
\title{title of document}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{brazil}
\frenchspacing 
\imprimircapa
%\imprimirfolhaderosto % <============== causes errors
\setlength{\absparsep}{18pt} 
\begin{resumo}  
\vspace{\onelineskip}
\end{resumo}
\begin{resumo}[Abstract]
\vspace{\onelineskip} 
\noindent 
\end{resumo}
\pdfbookmark[0]{\listfigurename}{lof}
\listoffigures*
\cleardoublepage
\pdfbookmark[0]{\listtablename}{lot}
\listoftables*
\cleardoublepage
%\begin{siglas}
%\end{siglas}
\pdfbookmark[0]{\contentsname}{toc}
\tableofcontents*
\cleardoublepage
\textual
\chapter{Introdução}
\section{Apresentação}
\phantompart
\postextual
\bibliography{Bibliografia}
\begin{apendicesenv}
\end{apendicesenv}
\begin{anexosenv}
\end{anexosenv}
\phantompart
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Please check the commented lines to evaluate the error there and change then your original code ...

Answer (score 1):

As predicted in the intial comment you have more `{` than `}`

```
\hypersetup{
```

has no matching `}`

Note that the full error message, which you did not show, shows exactly the problem starting with the `{` and saying it reached the end of the file

```
Runaway argument?
{ pdftitle={\@title }, pdfauthor={\@author }, pdfsubject={\imprimirpreambulo \E
TC.
! File ended while scanning use of \kvsetkeys.
<inserted text> 
                \par
```

`\kvsetkeys` is the internal command used by `\hypersetup` but the error message highlights the `{ pdftitle...` argument that is in your source file.

Comment: @Lucas just put a `}` before `\makeatother` to finish the `\hypersetup{` command. (and remove the `.` in the `indentfirst` line as noted in comments)

Comment: Thanks, David. The code is compiling now, although other errors appeared (for another topic).